# layout.xml text editor changes when clicked or highlighted in Eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

When I try to edit my layout.xml weird refresh of the text view happens and changes the text I click on (as if the line numbering in the text editor is messed up)

when I click on the text to edit it, it disappears and a duplicate of the line beneath appears

With every line I choose, the actual line goes away and another line duplicate on the line i select

just as if the editor is playing with me!! frustrating ...

I end up opening the xml from an editor outside Eclipse just for a simple edit.

P.S. I couldn't upload screen caps because of the points rule (Things just keep on getting better :P)

Comment: Save the layout.xml file before trying to edit

Comment: thatnx for the comment but I already tried that and I also build the project and that didn't help... I believe it's an editor issue for handling string numbering and messing reading the string line somehow when the caret is on it!!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the compatibility issues between Juno and the Android plugin have been fixed in ADT 20. Please update to the most recent version of ADT and SDK (which is 20.0.3 at the time as of now).